# firebase email verification fails in android 12 devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using android studio and firebase to design my app.  When user register in my app, I used to send an email with verification link to verify their email. The code I used for sending email verification link is shown below. It was working fine up to devices with android 11, and I  was successful in sending verification emails links to registered email ids using a line of code  " mAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification();" , but for android 12 devices it is not sending emails with verification links. I read "Verify Android App Links"  [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#add-intent-filters) in developer documents but I couldn't able to solve the issue.. Whether I need to do any change in code or I need do any addition in Manisfest file.. if any one knows please help

Comment: Yes mail came in spam folder

Answer (score 0):

Mail got in spam folder. if some faces this problem please check spam folder